# Set a selected option in menu dropdown with codeigniter

Tags: html, codeigniter, select

I chose to use  tag instead of `form_dropdown()` from Form Helper because i can't set a class atribute to `<option>` tag.
So I have a `<select>` and want to set a item with as `"selected"`. This data is coming from database. How I set this?
I saw this: `set_select()` but I can't make work.
Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: post your current code or what you have tried.

Comment: `<select name="myselect" id="myselect"> <option value="" <?php echo set_select('myselect', '', $home[0]->brand); ?>>--</option> <option value="apple" <?php echo set_select('myselect', 'apple', $home[0]->brand); ?>>AC</option> <option value="google" <?php echo set_select('myselect', 'google', $home[0]->brand); ?>>AM</option> </select>`

Answer (score 4):

From the [docs on the `form_dropdown` function](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html):

> form_dropdown()
>
> Lets you create a standard drop-down field. The first parameter will contain the name of the field, the second parameter will contain an associative array of options, and the **third parameter will contain the value you wish to be selected**.

```
echo form_dropdown('shirts', $options, 'large'); // 'large' will be "selected"
```

Comment: I chose to use tag instead of form_dropdown() from Form Helper because i can't set a class atribute to tag, and it's required in my application. Is there another solution?

Comment: HTML way... `<select> instead of <?php echo form_dropdown('shirts', $options, 'large'); ?>`.

Comment: Oh, I see. Well, in that case, @Ruben's answer below is correct (*Except that the third argument to `set_select` should be a boolean*).

Answer (score 2):

There are two things to keep in mind: First you have to use the validation class to be able to use the `set_select()` function. Second you have to pass the database information to that function, like this:

```
<select name="myselect">
  <option value="one" <?php echo set_select('myselect', 'one', ($model->selection == 'one')); ?> >One</option>
  <option value="two" <?php echo set_select('myselect', 'two', ($model->selection == 'two')); ?> >Two</option>
  <option value="three" <?php echo set_select('myselect', 'three', ($model->selection == 'three')); ?> >Three</option>
</select>
```

If `$model->selection` is `two`, then the second option will be selected in the example above.

Comment: I'm getting the value this way: `$home[0]->brand` but doesn't worked. The value of `$home[0]->brand` is correct, but with set_value doesn't work. `<select name="myselect" id="myselect">
    <option value="" <?php echo set_select('myselect', '', $home[0]->brand); ?>>--</option>
    <option value="apple" <?php echo set_select('myselect', 'apple', $home[0]->brand); ?>>AC</option>
    <option value="google" <?php echo set_select('myselect', 'google', $home[0]->brand); ?>>AM</option>
</select>`

Comment: The third argument to `set_select` should be a boolean, so you'd do something like this: `<option value="one" <?php echo set_select('myselect', 'one', ($model->selection == 'one')); ?> >One</option>`  -- [docs here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html)

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php echo form_label('Gender:'); ?>
<?php echo form_dropdown(array('id'=>'selectinform', 'name'=>'gender', 'options'=>array('1'=>'Select', '2'=>'2','3'=>'3'), 'selected'=>'1')); ?>

'selected'=>'1'
```

Comment: Please give more explanation even though code is explanatory